# Can I add PDFView through Storyboard in iOS 11

Tags: storyboard, ios11, apple-pdfkit

I am creating a PDF reader kind of App and for that, I am using `PDFKit` to show PDF files in that app.

I am able to add `PDFView` through code and it's working fine.

But is it possible that I can add `PDFView` through `storyboard` and then by Outlet I will assign a PDF file to that view?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create an `UIView` in your storyboard and give it the class `PDFView` in the identity inspector. You can then connect this view as usual via outlets. Connecting the methods like `goBack` as actions should also be possible.